# itext fill checkbox with value

Tags: .net, vb.net, pdf, uitextfield

On this PDF file [PDF File LINK](https://www.poreskaupravars.org/Documents/Doc/PD3100.pdf)

I have field which looks like this

[image]

By getting list of form fields i get names and i think the name of this field is `VrPr4` . Now when i try to populate that field with some value. Example want to check first box like this

```
     pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "1")
    'pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "Yes")
    'pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "ON")
```

[image: Checkbox not checked]

That is not the output i want. I need output like this

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues here, some in your code, some in the PDF:

#### Values of `VrPr4`

You tried

```
 pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "1")
'pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "Yes")
'pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "ON")
```

and none of these caused any of the field visualizations to appear marked. The reason is that neither of those values "1", "Yes", and "ON" are valid choices for this field. You can query the allowed choices using the `AcroFields` method `GetAppearanceStates`:

```
pdfFormFields.GetAppearanceStates("VrPr4")
```

It returns an array of names of available appearances and, therefore, allowed values of your field:

```
/** Gets the list of appearance names. Use it to get the names allowed
 * with radio and checkbox fields. If the /Opt key exists the values will
 * also be included. The name 'Off' may also be valid
 * even if not returned in the list.
 *  
 * For Comboboxes it will return an array of display values. To extract the
 * export values of a Combobox, please refer to {@link AcroFields#getListOptionExport(String)}
 *
 * @param fieldName the fully qualified field name
 * @return the list of names or <CODE>null</CODE> if the field does not exist
 */
virtual public String[] GetAppearanceStates(String fieldName)
```

In case of your field it returns `[No, Off, 0]`.

Using

```
pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "No")
```

one gets

[image: Result of simple pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "No")]

This is not yet what you want but at least the choice has become visible.

#### "Reader-enabled" document with JavaScript

The PDF in question is a so-called Reader-enabled document. This means that it is signed using a usage rights signature using a private key of Adobe. Furthermore it contains JavaScript changing form field appearances.

If for such a document you make the signature invalid, it may fundamentally change the way such a document reacts and appears.

The first step to not invalidate that signature is to use the `PdfStamper` in *append* mode; in this mode the original PDF is copied as is (so the signature still properly signs its byte range) and changes are appended as an "incremental update".

If in case of your document one uses *append* mode (using the four-parameter `PdfStamper` constructor with the boolean fourth parameter set to `true`) and opens the result in Adobe Reader, one gets:

[image: Result of append-mode pdfFormFields.SetField("VrPr4", "No")]